# Error while converting WKT to Geography data type in snowflake while using jdbc to insert data

Tags: jdbc, geometry, gis, geospatial, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying getting error when inserting wkt format data to geography column using JDBC.

The code I am using is

```
    private static final String QUERY_SNOWFLAKE = "INSERT INTO %s " +
            "(GEOM_AS_WKB, GEOM_AS_WKT, GEOID, NAMELSAD, TRACTCE, BLKGRPCE, INSIDE_CENTROID_LATITUDE, " +
            "INSIDE_CENTROID_LONGITUDE, AREA_SQUAREMILES, X_MIN, X_MAX, Y_MIN, Y_MAX, PART_COUNT, HOLE_COUNT, STATEFP, " +
            "COUNTYFP, STUSPS, STATE, COUNTY, VINTAGE, GEOM) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, " +
            "?, ?, ?, ?, ST_GEOGRAPHYFROMWKT(?))";

preparedStatementCENSUS_BLOCK_GROUP_GEOGRAPHY.setString(22,censusBlockGroupGeographyModel.getTheGeomText());
```

The error I am getting

Invalid expression [IFF(CAST(PARSE_WKT(?) AS VARIANT) IS NULL, null, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('_shape', CAST(PARSE_WKT(?) AS VARIANT), 'version', 1, 'has_internal', TRUE, 'internal', GEOGRAPHY_COMPUTE_INTERNAL(CAST(CAST(PARSE_WKT(?) AS VARIANT) AS OBJECT))))] in VALUES clause

Anyone has any idea about this error

Thanks

Comment: Wondering: Did you try the statement as is straight in Snowflake, not through jdbc? What were the results?

Comment: Yes in the snowflake it is working but using jdbc the same query is not working

Comment: What I don't understand: The error says that there's an invalid query containing things like `IFF` and `PARSE_WKT` -- which we can't find on the query posted. I think this question is missing relevant code.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Only this query is being run through JDBC, the error we are seeing is probably what is happening inside the function ST_GEOGRAPHYFROMWKT(?) when converting a wkt to geometry

Comment: Oh right - that makes sense. Can you also share the output of `censusBlockGroupGeographyModel.getTheGeomText()`?

Comment: The output is a wkt  MULTIPOLYGON (((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)),
((20 35, 45 20, 30 5, 10 10, 10 30, 20 35),
(30 20, 20 25, 20 15, 30 20)))
This is a sample data the real data is much bigger

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a WKT, WKB, or GeoJSON value into a GEOGRAPHY column directly without calling a parsing function. Snowflake will figure out the format of the value and attempt to parse it automatically. This should work for you:

```
private static final String QUERY_SNOWFLAKE = "INSERT INTO %s " +
        "(GEOM_AS_WKB, GEOM_AS_WKT, GEOID, NAMELSAD, TRACTCE, BLKGRPCE, INSIDE_CENTROID_LATITUDE, " +
        "INSIDE_CENTROID_LONGITUDE, AREA_SQUAREMILES, X_MIN, X_MAX, Y_MIN, Y_MAX, PART_COUNT, HOLE_COUNT, STATEFP, " +
        "COUNTYFP, STUSPS, STATE, COUNTY, VINTAGE, GEOM) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, " +
        "?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

preparedStatementCENSUS_BLOCK_GROUP_GEOGRAPHY.setString(22,censusBlockGroupGeographyModel.getTheGeomText());
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. It really helped.